# Check if delimiters are balanced, and if they aren't give the location where the error occurs

Tags: java, counter, stack

I am having trouble with my "Matching delimiters" Java code.

First of all, I need help with the character counter. A few friends suggested a line counter, I don't know which to use or how exactly to implement them within my code.

Second, I'm supposed to do multi line comments as well "/* .... */. I understand the logic

- check for "/"
- if found, check if next character is `*`
- push into my slash stack
- check for `*`
- if found, check if next character is `/`
- print my message
- pop my slash stack..

But I can't seem to find out how to do so without my working counter. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
private Stack<Character> parenthesisStack = new Stack<Character>();
private Stack<Character> braceStack = new Stack<Character>();
private Stack<Character> bracketStack = new Stack<Character>();
private Stack<Character> slashStack = new Stack<Character>();

public void Match(String input) {
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
        char currentGroupingSymbol = input.charAt(j);

        switch (currentGroupingSymbol) {
            case '(':
                parenthesisStack.push(currentGroupingSymbol);
                break;

            case '[':
                braceStack.push(currentGroupingSymbol);
                break;

            case '{':
                bracketStack.push(currentGroupingSymbol);
                break;


            case ')':
                if (!parenthesisStack.isEmpty()) {
                    if (currentGroupingSymbol == ')' && parenthesisStack.peek() == '(') {
                        System.out.println("The Parenthesis are Balanced");
                        parenthesisStack.pop();

                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Where is the matching parenthesis for " + currentGroupingSymbol + " at character " + j + "?");
                }
                break;

            case ']':
                if (!braceStack.isEmpty()) {
                    if (currentGroupingSymbol == ']' && braceStack.peek() == '[') {
                        System.out.println("The Braces are Balanced");
                        braceStack.pop();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Where is the matching brace for " + currentGroupingSymbol + " at character " + j + "?");
                }
                break;

            case '}':
                if (!bracketStack.isEmpty()) {
                    if (currentGroupingSymbol == '}' && bracketStack.peek() == '{') {
                        System.out.println("The Brackets are Balanced");
                        bracketStack.pop();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Where is the matching bracket for " + currentGroupingSymbol + " at character " + j + "?");
                }
                break;

            case '/':
                slashStack.push(currentGroupingSymbol);
                if (input.charAt(j+1) == '/' ) {
                    System.out.println("Look at you with proper comments!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Be careful! This " + currentGroupingSymbol + " could mean division! ");
                }
        }
    }
    if (!parenthesisStack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You have one or more too many open Parenthesis");
    }
    if (!braceStack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You have one or more too many open Braces");
    }
    if (!bracketStack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You have one or more too many open Brackets");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a file name");
    String fileName = scan.nextLine();
    File testFile = new File(fileName);


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
    String input = new String();
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        build.append(input);
    }
    Match prog = new Match();
    prog.Match(build.toString());
}
```

Comment: What's the actual question/problem you're having here?  Your sketched-out logic looks fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: The brace/bracket/paren stacks should probably really be one stack - you're checking whether they're balanced, that is whether a closing paren you found is of the same type as the last open one. Also in most languages you can't nest `/* … */` comments - you don't need a stack for that, just a `boolean` flag you turn on and off. If it's on, you ignore any characters except a comment end. (That is, you neither push to or pop from the paren stack.)

Comment: I figured it out. my problem was easily solved by moving everything into one stack and peeking at what followed the / and checking if it was a star. also i figured out my counter by bothering my professor to death. thanks guys!